# Redirect from ASP to ASP.Net Session

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic

I am redirecting from a classic ASP page to an ASP.Net page on a different webserver. The landing aspx page seems to start a new session after postback i.e. my session variables which are set when the page is first hit after the redirect, are being reset after a button on the page is clicked. How do I work around this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had a look at the HTTP headers being sent to the server in each of the two cases: when redirecting from ASP and from ASP.Net.  I noticed that in the case of ASP.Net a cookie was being sent ASP.Net_SessionID. This was not being sent from the ASP page. I did some reading and found out that you can set ASP.Net to run cookieless - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx. I added the

```
    sessionState cookieless="true"
```

to my web.config and all is well. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read ["How to Share Session State Between Classic ASP and ASP.NET"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx).

But you should know from start, there's no way to just pass the sessions between asp and asp.net using the session-object in both of them.

Read the above article and you'll know all about it!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a page explaining how to share session data between classic ASP en ASP.NET.
You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx)

Comment: Let me explain a bit more... I am not trying the share state. I redirect from ASP to an ASP.Net page on a different server (test.aspx). The test.aspx page creates a few session vars. When a button on that page is clicked causing a postback, the session vars are lost. This does not happen when I go directly to the test.aspx page without the redirection from the asp page.

Comment: ASP Page: 
    <% response.redirect("test.aspx?uid=hippo") %>  

ASP.Net Page: 
Page_Load
    if(Session["test"] != null) Response.Write(Session["test"].ToString());  
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) Session["test"] = Request.QueryString("uid");  

Button_Click: 
    Response.Write(Session["test"].ToString());  

The Button_Click "event" throws a null reference exception.

Comment: One more thing - if I replace the asp page with an asp.net page still using the two different servers, it works.

Comment: Thanks, I am using IIS6, so maybe I'll check if there is a configuration issue of some sort.